# Determine if current user has write access for google sheet

Tags: javascript, rest, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Sheets API from a Javascript application.

Users log in to my app and grant it permission read/write permission to google sheets.

I have hardcoded a document ID for a google sheet into my application.

I want to be able to make a rest query to determine the current users access rights to that particular document. The user may have:

- no access
- read only access
- read write access

(I manually share the relevant access to the document to each user)

I am looking for a way of doing this. I have searched the sheets API and the drive API but I can't find any call.

At the moment I plan to create a function which will:

1. try and read the document - if I get an error return "NO ACCESS"
2. try and write the document - if I get an error return "READ ONLY"
3. return "READ WRITE"

It seems like a bad idea to determine write access by actually making a write to the document.
Does anyone have any better ideas?

I have tried listing the permissions using this API:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/list
but I just get a list of permissions and this has to be parsed. Also my test read only user got forbidden.

Comment: Based from this [blog](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/development-resources/confluence-developer-faq/how-do-i-tell-if-a-user-has-permission-to), you can check for the [permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/update) assigned to the user. Example: To check if your user has permission to edit a particular page, the call is:  `permissionManager.hasPermission(myUser, Permission.EDIT, thePage)`.

Comment: Also from this [document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound), you can use simple triggers which runs automatically whenever a file is opened by a user who has edit access. You can check on this [tutorial](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-drive-access/28237/) to know who has access to your Google Drive files and folders.